# The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_Employees_Departments"

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, linq

I have database of employees and the departments where they work in.
I have old DB and new DB and both of them have the same properties, but with different data.
I want to copy data from old DB to new DB and save changes. But I have a problem when inserting employees because the id of department and employee is identity so I can't copy and insert them.

I add this line:

`db2.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[destEmployees] ON");`

but still have error

> SqlException: The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_Employees_Departments". The conflict occurred in database "Destination", table "dbo.destDepartments", column 'Id'.
>   The statement has been terminated.

```
db2.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("SET IDENTITY_INSERT [destDepartments] ON");

foreach (var item in destDeps)
{
    db2.destDepartments.Add(item);
}

db2.SaveChanges();

db2.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(" SET IDENTITY_INSERT[dbo].[destDepartments] OFF");

db2.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("SET IDENTITY_INSERT [destEmployees] ON");
foreach (var item in destEmps)
{
    db2.destEmployees.Add(item);
}

db2.SaveChanges();
db2.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("SET IDENTITY_INSERT [destEmployees] OFF");
```

Comment: What do you think that exception means?

Comment: You could disable your constraints while inserting data and then enable them again afterwards:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/disable-foreign-key-constraints-with-insert-and-update-statements?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: when it try to add employees with their department id which founded in old database , it dose not found the same id of department in new DB because it was generated automatic as IDENTITY

Comment: @MJH how i do it using entity framework ?

Comment: @Gehad: If the identifiers used by the FK relationships are different in the new DB, how do you expect to be able to insert the exact same data?  Even if it doesn't fail, it's going to point to the wrong record.  You need to find out what the correct record is and use that one.  Or copy the data with the same identifiers.

Comment: Usually this happens If you try to add value in foreign key column which is not there in its relative primary key table.

Comment: does the following request returns any result :`select DepartmentId from Employees where DepartmentId not in (select Id from Departments)` ?

Comment: @tschmit007 no result

Comment: can you post the definition of `FK_Employees_Departments`

Comment: @tschmit007 there can't be any results. Any results appearing in this query would violate the FK constraint and cannot be inserted (assuming DepartmentId is the FK from Employees->Departments)

Comment: @DevilSuichiro, I know, I wanted to check if the constraint on the destination tables was also present on the source tables

Comment: @tschmit007 you already knew the constraint was present, otherwise the FK constraint failed would have not been returned.

Answer (score 0):

the easiest workaround here is get the max ID from the department table  in your new DB and add it to the id from your old DB (for both department and employee) then do the insert.

Answer (score 0):

Since there is a relationship (you *did* mention FK), how are the Department Ids in the copied Employees getting updated to the correct Ids of the "new" departments?

In the abstract, you are going to need to track the "old" id of each department coupled to the "new" id.  Then, when you are copying the employees, update the link (Department Id) to the new Id.